# Chart.JS format date in label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How do you format the date in a datapoint's label in Chart.JS?

I've tried this:

```
this.chart = new Chart(ctx,
  {
    data: {
      labels: timestamps 
                .map(t => t.toLocaleString([], { month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })),
      datasets: [
        {
          data: measurements
        }, 
        //etc...
]}});
```

It works, but I get a Moment.JS warning message:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format... Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.

Is there a proper way to format dates for data labels in Chart.JS since the method I am using is apparently discouraged?

**With `labels: timestamps`**

[image: chart showing default date format]

**With `labels: timestamps.map(t => t.toLocaleString(...)`**

[image: chart showing localeString format]

Comment: The warning you're getting is about what the original date string values look like. I don't think the code you posted would do that because there are no Moment calls in it.

Comment: chart.js uses MomentJS's date format specifications. As per their [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html?h=date%20format): "When providing data for the time scale, Chart.js supports all of the formats that Moment.js accepts."

Comment: If I change the labels to not include `.map(...)`, the warning goes away.

Comment: Right but what is the `timestamps` array in the first place? Where does it come from? What is the type of the contents; are they strings or Date instances?

Comment: `timestamps` is a `Date[]`. It is populated by `timestamps = this.dataPoints.map(x => x.timeStampDt);`. Whereas `measurements` is populated by `measurements = this.dataPoints.map(x => x.measurement)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was able to find the answer by inspecting the source HTML file of [a sample chart](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line.html) provided by Chart.js.

In order to format the dates properly, one must add the parser and tooltipFormat properties to the axis in question. To fix my example given above:

```
this.chart = new Chart(ctx,
  {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: timestamps,
      datasets: [
        {
          data: measurements,
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [ {
            display: true,
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              parser: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
              tooltipFormat: 'll HH:mm',
              unit: 'day',
              unitStepSize: 1,
              displayFormats: {
                'day': 'MM/DD/YYYY'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        yAxis: [
          // etc...
        ],
      }
    }
  }
);
```

### EDIT (1/17/2023)

The sample chart that I linked initially has been removed from the Chart.js documentation. Here's their latest link regarding time scales: [Time Cartesian Axis | Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html)

Comment: If you tried this but got "Uncaught Error: This method is not implement..." you might need to include a date library and date adapter. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69335631/3761310 and this section of the docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/time.html